# jQuery issue with Propagation and Keydown

Tags: jquery

I had gotten help earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369208/jquery-keydown-and-not-with-inputs) with what turned out to be a propagation issue, but I am now trying to use [HTML5 autofocus](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#autofocus) on an input and now my code breaks.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(':not(form)').keydown(function(event) {

    $j('form').keydown(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    if(event.keyCode==82) {
        $j(document).trigger(location.href = '/?random')
    }
});
</script>
```

Basically, I have some keyboard navigation set up. If you press R, it takes you to a random page.

I was trying to disable that functionality when a user was typing in a form/input box, for obvious reasons. This code works, EXCEPT when I try to use autofocus. If you start typing right on the pageload, and the first letter you type is R, it goes to a random page.

If another letter is typed first, then R gets entered as a normal letter. I'm kind of a newbie at this stuff, so any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: Upon further testing, it appears the issue might not be the autofocus, but mainly that just when the first letter typed is an R, it bugs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your selector with "not" was not correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode==82) {
            $(document).trigger(location.href = '/?random')
        }
    });
    $('input, textarea').keydown(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` really stops the event, adding `return false` will do `event.preventDefault();` too

Comment: stopPropagation doesn't stop the event. It stops the event from bubbling up the tree.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. :) Your answer is missing the `</script>` and I need to use `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` because I am working with WordPress, but this is great.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you're adding a keydown event to the form element every time keydown is called on any other element.

Try this out.. I changed your JS a bit...

http://jsfiddle.net/CAjNR/1/

Here's the code from the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" autofocus />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div id="results">
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode | event.which;
    if(key==82) {
        $j('#results').append($j('<div>pressed: r</div>'));
    }
});
$j('input, textarea').keydown(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: `event.keycode | event.which` probably needs to be `event.keycode || event.which`

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I still can't get it to work. I changed `$j('#results').append($j('<div>pressed: r</div>'));` from your code to `$j(document).trigger(location.href = '/?random');` to test locally on my site and pressing R anytime in the input (not just first letter now) makes it go to the random page.